# Can I check what challenges I have completed during a mission?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'd like to know which singleplayer campaign challenges I have completed, as well as refresh my memory of what some of them are. Can I do this while on the mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to check which challenges you have completed during a mission.

Answer (score 2):

Durning the game just hit pause and it will show you the missions you need to accomplish as well as the missions you have completed

Comment: I only see "Resume game", "Options", "Restart mission" and "Quit".